# Numpy: When applying a boolean mask for an array of arrays, most efficient way to record which items were in the original arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I can perform a boolean mask on an array of arrays like this

```
import numpy as np 
a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
b = [[True, False, False], [True, True, False], [False, False, False]]
np.array(a)[np.array(b)]
```

and get `array([1, 4, 5])`

How would I preserve the information of which numbers belonged to the same array?

something like this would work

```
is_in_original(1, 4)
> False
is_in_origina(5, 4)
>True
```

One thing I could think of is this

```
def is_in_original(x, y):
    for arry in np.array(a):
        if x in arry and y in arry:
            return True
    return False
```

I am wondering if this is the most computationally efficient method. I will be working with very large array of arrays, and need the throughput to be as fast as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `np.where(mask, array, 0)` to preserve dimensions.

```
import numpy as np 
a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
b = [[True, False, False], [True, True, False], [False, False, False]]
ret = np.where(np.array(b), np.array(a), 0)
```

Output:

```
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [4, 5, 0],
       [0, 0, 0]])
```

In this case you can change third parameter of `np.where` is 0, you can change the value to any number or `inf`